# Updating child props value on parent props value change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, user-interface, components

guys! I'm building React Native component that contains a UI pattern. This UI pattern will contain several smaller reusable patterns. This way:

```
<ListItem onPress={}>
  <IconContainer>
    <Icon />
  </IconContainer>
  <Body>
    <Text>Content</Text>
  </Body>
  <Right>
    <Action onPress={} />
  </Right>
<ListItem>
```

Now I'm also building embedding size variants (`small`, `medium/default` and `large`) for some of these children, like this for example:

```
<IconContainer large={boolean} small={boolean}>
  <Icon />
</IconContainer>
```

And since the are several children, I don't want to have the person using the component to have to specify the size variant for each one of the children. That'll also require them to know which one of the children have size variants and which one doesn't.

So, what I'm trying to do is to embed a `props.large` and a `props.small` into the parent and use that to change de value of the same `prop` if available in the children.

Any ideas of how to do that in a simple way?
(I suspect this is easy but I've been struggling with this for a while so I thought I'd ask for some help.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: read about react context

Comment: OK, I will. Thank you!